# openssl support for cryptodev-linux

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, embedded-linux, gnutls

Looks like openssl comes with cryptodev-linux support(through eng_cryptodev.c) .
When I download openssl,eng_cryptodev.c file is available by default.

below link refers about eng_cryptodev.c for openssl support :

http://repo.or.cz/w/cryptodev-linux.git/commitdiff/56cc4e3b8b761cb34f928f4eee59755d1f0afc53

Note:looks like there are some additional changes done on  eng_cryptodev.c file available in openssl source.

There seems to be some changes/patches  also available recently for cryptodev-linux,below contains reference information.

http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2770&user=guest&pass=guest

patches are:

0001-cryptodev-Fix-issue-with-signature-generation.patch
0002-cryptodev-allow-copying-EVP-contexts.patch

Note: patch -p0 < 0001/2-*.patch does not work properly.so applied manually.

Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect .

BR,

& Sanumala

Comment: Take a look at these [slides](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lcj-2014-crypto-user.pdf) for crypto support in OpenSSL.